Programming failed with error message "[ Pgm ] at 0x1d000040, expected 0x8fc30008, got 0x8bc30008."
I am getting the above error while programming PIC MCU
Following are the things I am using:

PIC32MX675F512L
MPLAB X IDE V6.20
PICKit5

Here is full error:
Connecting to MPLAB PICkit 5



Currently loaded versions:

Application version...........02.01.83

Boot version..................00.00.10

PCB version...................2

Script version................00.07.47

Script build number...........974b928e70

Tool pack version ............2.5.391

Target voltage detected

Target device PIC32MX675F512L found.

Device Revision Id = 0xA5

Device Id = 0x11000



Calculating memory ranges for operation...



Erasing...



The following memory area(s) will be programmed:

program memory: start address = 0x1d000000, end address = 0x1d000fff

configuration memory

boot config memory



 [ Pgm ] at 0x1d000040, expected 0x8fc30008, got 0x8bc30008.

Programming did not complete.

Here is my code:
// PIC32MX675F512L Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// DEVCFG3

#pragma config USERID = 0xFFFF     // Enter Hexadecimal value (Enter Hexadecimal value)
#pragma config FSRSSEL = PRIORITY_7   // SRS Select (SRS Priority 7)
#pragma config FMIIEN = OFF       // Ethernet RMII/MII Enable (MII Enabled)
#pragma config FETHIO = OFF       // Ethernet I/O Pin Select (Default Ethernet I/O)
#pragma config FUSBIDIO = OFF      // USB USID Selection (Controlled by the USB Module)
#pragma config FVBUSONIO = ON      // USB VBUS ON Selection (Controlled by USB Module)

// DEVCFG2

#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_12    // PLL Input Divider (12x Divider)
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_24     // PLL Multiplier (24x Multiplier)
#pragma config UPLLIDIV = DIV_12    // USB PLL Input Divider (12x Divider)
#pragma config UPLLEN = OFF       // USB PLL Enable (Disabled and Bypassed)
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_256    // System PLL Output Clock Divider (PLL Divide by 256)

// DEVCFG1

#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIV      // Oscillator Selection Bits (Fast RC Osc w/Div-by-N (FRCDIV))
#pragma config FSOSCEN = ON       // Secondary Oscillator Enable (Enabled)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal/External Switch Over (Enabled)
#pragma config POSCMOD = OFF      // Primary Oscillator Configuration (Primary osc disabled)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF      // CLKO Output Signal Active on the OSCO Pin (Disabled)
#pragma config FPBDIV = DIV_8      // Peripheral Clock Divisor (Pb_Clk is Sys_Clk/8)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD      // Clock Switching and Monitor Selection (Clock Switch Disable, FSCM Disabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = PS1048576    // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:1048576)
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT Enabled)

// DEVCFG0

#pragma config DEBUG = OFF       // Background Debugger Enable (Debugger is disabled)
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx1    // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select (ICE EMUC2/EMUD2 pins shared with PGC2/PGD2)
#pragma config PWP = OFF        // Program Flash Write Protect (Disable)
#pragma config BWP = OFF        // Boot Flash Write Protect bit (Protection Disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protect (Protection Disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.

// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#define SYS_FREQ 80000000UL

void delay_us(unsigned int us) {
    // Convert microseconds us into how many clock ticks it will take 
    us *= SYS_FREQ / 1000000 / 2; // Core Timer updates every 2 ticks (In case of 8MHz frequency result is 0.4 clock ticks)

    // This line is not fully clear
    _CP0_SET_COUNT(0); // Set Core Timer count to 0

    while (us > _CP0_GET_COUNT()); // Wait until Core Timer count reaches the number we calculated earlier
}

void led_toggle(void) {
    LATAbits.LATA7 = 1;
    delay_us(1000000);
    LATAbits.LATA7 = 0;
    delay_us(1000000);
}

int main(void) {
    TRISAbits.TRISA7 = 0;

    while (1) {
        led_toggle();
    }

    return 0;
}

Observation No.1:
One very Important observation I want to share with all of you that: When I program the controller again after 12/13 hours then it programs successfully and my led connected to PORTA pin 7 is blinking perfectly. But after I upload the same code or any other code for 6-7 times or in some cases 4-5 times then it starts throwing me same error.
Observation No.2:
Sometimes it give me same error on different memory locations: Mostly on 1d000040 Sometimes: 1d000440 and 1d000840

Have you tried anything to debug? A quick google search showed other people have had this issue before and successfully fixed it via a number of solutions.

At a guess perhaps the PICkit5 has the PGC clock set too fast. Try selecting a slower clock rate for programming the target controller.

InBedded16:
Before posting this query I have tried the solutions people are reffering to on this forum and also on microchip's forum.
One of the most common solution they gave are changing the memory range which most of people did and solved this issue. But my error still persists even after changing the memory range.

Dan1138: Yes I have tried that before by setting the slower clock rate but still it is showing me same error.

InBedded16 and Dan1138: I have added 2 important observations at the end of my post. Please read them and help me out.
